# Sum values from one table based on keys in another table.

Tags: sql, sql-update

Have two tables. First is based by "play" and has a column of 0 and 1 based on other criteria. Second table is based of groups of plays (series). I want to add the sum of the correct plays' value column to the right key in the second table.

```
TABLE 1
Gamekey. Series. Playid. Value. 
111.       1.      1.      0
111.       1.      2.      1
111.       1.      3.      1
111.       2.      1.      0
111.       3.      1.      1
111.       3.      2.      0
112.       1.      1.      0
112.       2.      1.      1


TABLE 2
Gamekey.  Series.  Sum of value <-- column I need
111.        1.          2
111.        2.          0
111.        3.          1
112.        1.          0
112.        2.          1
```

FYI - series always starts with 1 and increases by 1. Max number values of series differs by game. Gamekey is not always consecutive.

Comment: Need more information, clearer data 11.1.1. looks like binary lol

Comment: Sorry. Looked better in the text box.

Comment: Row 1 is  = 111.  Series = 1.  Playid = 1. Value = 0.   Row 2 is gamekey = 111, etc

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to really parse what you're looking for, but it looks like you might want,

```
SELECT GameKey, Series, Sum(Value) AS SumOfValue FROM Table1 GROUP BY GameKey, Series
```

Comment: How would I actually be able to add the sum value to the right gamekey/series in table 2?  Thanks for the quick response BTW!

Comment: What result set are you expecting? I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

What I've written above will give you Table2 based on Table1 as input.

Comment: I ultimately have a bunch of different value columns to add.  I was thinking I need to add the sum value to table 2, but now I think I was mistaken. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry. In my attempt to ask simply, I didn't mention that I have other columns in table 2 I also need in the select statement. These columns do not occur in table 1. Your answer is perfect for just the three column (gamekey,series,sum), but how would it need to be structured to included "netyards" and "firstdowns" in table 2.  This is why I assumed it would need to be inserted into table 2, rather than select